# How to send a notification using at command?

Tags: command-line, at-command

I have a bash script that runs periodically once a day using `crontab`.

The script checks a condition, and if true, it should issue an `at command` at a specific time.

`at 14:10 <notify-send hello>`

The question is: how can I add a specific command like `notify-send` to the `at` command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
echo "notify-send 'hello'" | at 14:10
```

`at` is expecting a command from STDIN.

If you want to silence the `/bin/sh` warning, run it this way:

```
echo "notify-send 'hello'" | at 14:10 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I am testing your command I see this error `warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh`, what does it mean?

Comment: This means literally what is said. `/bin/sh` will be used as a shell for the command. It is OK if you are worried.

Comment: @George I added how to silence the warning.

Comment: ok but I prefer to see it in case I did something dumb :)

Comment: This is useless use of `echo` and pipe. A [Here String](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) would be more appropriate: `at 14:10 <<< "notify-send hello"`.

Comment: @Ruslan It is an option too. I use it both ways. It looks better as `command | at <time>` ;-)

Comment: @Ruslan does it make any practical difference for shells such as bash and dash, where `echo` is a shell builtin?

Comment: @steeldriver In this case it makes no difference. For some other commands there may be a difference.

Comment: Regarding @Ruslan comment it makes no difference at all.

Comment: `warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh` warn you that the command will be run as `/bin/sh`, this is important because `dash` (the default command interpreter for ubuntu is not 100% compatible with `bash` (which is probably the shell you're using).

Answer (score 2):

As I was searching for a fast way to remind myself using dunstify/notify-send I want to promote [@Ruslan 's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924598/how-to-send-a-notification-using-at-command/924601#comment1461313_924601), because it involves less typing (which is essential when you want to "just set a timer")

```
at now + 3minutes <<< "notify-send -t 0 'tee is ready'"
```

... or with less whitespace/characters:

```
at now+3min<<<'notify-send -t 0 tee isready'
```

- `-t 0` don't timeout the notification and keep it open

and just for information:
as an improvement to `atq` or `at -l` listing I use an alias that also **prints the executed command**, not just time/queue/user:

```
alias ,atl='for j in $(atq | sort -k6,6 -k3,3M -k4,4 -k5,5 |cut -f 1); do atq |grep -P "^$j\t" ;at -c "$j" | tail -n 2; done'
```

([as mentioned here in serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/837582/290859))

** tested with Manjaro21/Debian10*